# Pyspark conver the column into list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my pyspark dataframe, there is a column which is being inferred as string, but it is actually a List. I need to convert the same into list

Sample Value of the column :

`[{"@ID":"07D40CB5-273E-4814-B82C-B5DCA7145D20","@ProductName":"Event Registration","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Admission Item","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@Status":"Active"},{"CustomFieldDetail":{"@FieldName":"Description","@FieldType":"Open Ended Text - Comment Box","@FieldValue":null,"@FieldId":"C6D46AD1-9B3F-45FF-9331-27EA47811E37"},"@ID":"8EA83E8B-7573-4550-905D-D4320496AD89","@ProductName":"Test","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Session","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@StartTime":"2018-01-29T18:00:00","@EndTime":"2018-01-29T19:00:00","@Status":"Active"}]`

Please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: Do you have the same json keys in all records?  Do you need specific values?

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic solution that first converts the JSON strings column to an RDD, then read the RDD to a dataframe and finally makes use of the inferred schema to read the original dataframe while parsing the JSON strings.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
```

This is not part of the solution, only creation of the sample dataframe

```
str1 =  '''[{"@ID":"str1_1","a":11},{"@ID":"str1_2","d":[41,42,43]}]'''
str2 =  '''[{"@ID":"str2_1","a":101},{"@ID":"str2_2","c":301},{"@ID":"str2_3","b":201,"nested":{"a":1001,"b":2001}}]'''

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, str1,),(2, str2,)],['id', 'json_str'])
```

This is the actual solution

```
df_json_str = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda x:x.json_str))
json_str_schema = T.ArrayType(df_json_str.schema)

df = df.withColumn('json_str', F.from_json('json_str',json_str_schema))
```

---

```
df_json_str.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- @ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- nested: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

---

```
df.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- json_str: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- @ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- nested: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

---

```
df.show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |json_str                                                                                                                     |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{str1_1, 11, null, null, null, null}, {str1_2, null, null, null, [41, 42, 43], null}]                                       |
|2  |[{str2_1, 101, null, null, null, null}, {str2_2, null, null, 301, null, null}, {str2_3, null, 201, null, null, {1001, 2001}}]|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A quick demonstration that everything is fine with the result and the dataframe is exploding well

```
df_explode = df.selectExpr('id', 'inline(json_str)')
```

---

```
df_explode.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- @ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- nested: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

---

```
df_explode.show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+---+------+----+----+----+------------+------------+
|id |@ID   |a   |b   |c   |d           |nested      |
+---+------+----+----+----+------------+------------+
|1  |str1_1|11  |null|null|null        |null        |
|1  |str1_2|null|null|null|[41, 42, 43]|null        |
|2  |str2_1|101 |null|null|null        |null        |
|2  |str2_2|null|null|301 |null        |null        |
|2  |str2_3|null|201 |null|null        |{1001, 2001}|
+---+------+----+----+----+------------+------------+
```

---

**Demonstration on OP sample**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
```

This is not part of the solution, only creation of the sample dataframe

```
str1 = '''[{"@ID":"07D40CB5-273E-4814-B82C-B5DCA7145D20","@ProductName":"Event Registration","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Admission Item","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@Status":"Active"},{"CustomFieldDetail":{"@FieldName":"Description","@FieldType":"Open Ended Text - Comment Box","@FieldValue":null,"@FieldId":"C6D46AD1-9B3F-45FF-9331-27EA47811E37"},"@ID":"8EA83E8B-7573-4550-905D-D4320496AD89","@ProductName":"Test","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Session","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@StartTime":"2018-01-29T18:00:00","@EndTime":"2018-01-29T19:00:00","@Status":"Active"}]'''

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, str1,)],['id', 'json_str'])

df_json_str = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda x:x.json_str))
```

---

```
df_json_str.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- @EndTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @ProductCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @ProductDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @ProductName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @SessionCategoryId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @SessionCategoryName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @StartTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- @Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomFieldDetail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @FieldId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @FieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @FieldType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @FieldValue: string (nullable = true)
```

---

```
json_str_schema = T.ArrayType(df_json_str.schema)

df = df.withColumn('json_str', F.from_json('json_str',json_str_schema))
```

---

```
df.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- json_str: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- @EndTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @ProductCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @ProductDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @ProductName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @SessionCategoryId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @SessionCategoryName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @StartTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @Status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CustomFieldDetail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- @FieldId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- @FieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- @FieldType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- @FieldValue: string (nullable = true)
```

---

```
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |json_str                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{null, 07D40CB5-273E-4814-B82C-B5DCA7145D20, null, null, Event Registration, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, null, null, Active, Admission Item, null}, {2018-01-29T19:00:00, 8EA83E8B-7573-4550-905D-D4320496AD89, null, null, Test, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, null, 2018-01-29T18:00:00, Active, Session, {C6D46AD1-9B3F-45FF-9331-27EA47811E37, Description, Open Ended Text - Comment Box, null}}]|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
df.selectExpr('id', 'inline(json_str)').show(truncate=False)

+---+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |@EndTime           |@ID                                 |@ProductCode|@ProductDescription|@ProductName      |@SessionCategoryId                  |@SessionCategoryName|@StartTime         |@Status|@Type         |CustomFieldDetail                                                                       |
+---+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |null               |07D40CB5-273E-4814-B82C-B5DCA7145D20|null        |null               |Event Registration|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|null                |null               |Active |Admission Item|null                                                                                    |
|1  |2018-01-29T19:00:00|8EA83E8B-7573-4550-905D-D4320496AD89|null        |null               |Test              |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|null                |2018-01-29T18:00:00|Active |Session       |{C6D46AD1-9B3F-45FF-9331-27EA47811E37, Description, Open Ended Text - Comment Box, null}|
+---+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

This solution is relevant if you know the schema in advance.
It is off course more effective performance vise than inferring the schema.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

myval = '''[{"@ID":"07D40CB5-273E-4814-B82C-B5DCA7145D20","@ProductName":"Event Registration","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Admission Item","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@Status":"Active"},{"CustomFieldDetail":{"@FieldName":"Description","@FieldType":"Open Ended Text - Comment Box","@FieldValue":null,"@FieldId":"C6D46AD1-9B3F-45FF-9331-27EA47811E37"},"@ID":"8EA83E8B-7573-4550-905D-D4320496AD89","@ProductName":"Test","@ProductCode":null,"@Type":"Session","@ProductDescription":null,"@SessionCategoryName":null,"@SessionCategoryId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","@StartTime":"2018-01-29T18:00:00","@EndTime":"2018-01-29T19:00:00","@Status":"Active"}]'''

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, myval,)], 'id int, myjson string')
```

---

```
myschema = F.schema_of_json(mylist)


# -------------- or -----------------
# myschema = spark.sql(f"select schema_of_json('{mylist}')").first()[0]
# print (myschema)

# ARRAY<STRUCT<`@EndTime`: STRING, `@ID`: STRING, `@ProductCode`: STRING, `@ProductDescription`: STRING, `@ProductName`: STRING, `@SessionCategoryId`: STRING, `@SessionCategoryName`: STRING, `@StartTime`: STRING, `@Status`: STRING, `@Type`: STRING, `CustomFieldDetail`: STRUCT<`@FieldId`: STRING, `@FieldName`: STRING, `@FieldType`: STRING, `@FieldValue`: STRING>>>
# -----------------------------------


df = df.withColumn('myjson', F.from_json('myjson',myschema))
```

---

```
df.show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|              myjson|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[{null, 07D40CB5-...|
+---+--------------------+
```

---

```
df.selectExpr('id', 'inline(myjson)').show()

+---+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+--------------------+
| id|           @EndTime|                 @ID|@ProductCode|@ProductDescription|      @ProductName|  @SessionCategoryId|@SessionCategoryName|         @StartTime|@Status|         @Type|   CustomFieldDetail|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+--------------------+
|  1|               null|07D40CB5-273E-481...|        null|               null|Event Registration|00000000-0000-000...|                null|               null| Active|Admission Item|                null|
|  1|2018-01-29T19:00:00|8EA83E8B-7573-455...|        null|               null|              Test|00000000-0000-000...|                null|2018-01-29T18:00:00| Active|       Session|{C6D46AD1-9B3F-45...|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: problem is, I have to dynamically pass the schema as some records will have 3 elements inside the string list, some has 4 and so on...

Comment: See updated answer